# How to get contacts of user on exchange 2013 when have full permission on user's mailboxes

Tags: migration, exchange-2013, mailbox, outlook-2013, contacts

I want to export user's contacts into .csv file without knowing his password. 
Now, I can give an account `admin` full permission to user mailboxes by this `cmdlet`:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity abc@example.com -User admin -AccessRights FullAccess
```

My question is, with this `admin` account how can I access and export contacts of `abc@example.com`?

Or if you have any idea to do this, could you please hint me?

Thx,

Comment: Try the following `New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox <user> -IncludeFolders “#Contacts#” - ExcludeDumpster -filepath c:\some\path\contacts.pst `

Comment: `New-MailboxExportRequest` cmdlet seems to available for exchange 2016 only. thx anw

Comment: 2010 onwards? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459227(v=exchg.141).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the mailbox in Outlook and open the second mailbox in Folder view. 
[image: Outlook Folder View]

The Contacts folder will be visible and you can select all items there. Or, **File > Export** should work to get you a CSV file.

[image: Outlook Export Folder Selection]

Comment: Posted from mobile, needs improvement.

Comment: I will try your guide tomorrow and let you know. Now i don't have outlook.